# Is it possible to recursively multiply 2 floats?

Tags: python, recursion

my homework is "Write a function that takes in two numbers and recursively multiplies them together", the solution for integers appears in the website in few questions, but is is possible for floats i wrote a code that can handle one float but I can't imagine how to deal with 2 as a novice i wonder is there such possibility that's my code

```
def multy(n, m):
    # deals with one float situation
    if m % 1 != 0:
        return multy(m, n)
    else: 
        if m == 0:
            return 0
        elif m < 0:
            return -(n - multy(n, m+1))
        else:
            return n + multy(n, m-1)
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible with floats. But you can try to convert the float-point in fixed-point numbers represented as int and continue as before. You will have a limited range, depending on the required precision.

Answer (score 1):

You can "convert" your float to int and use your multy function, then "convert" it back to the float:

```
def fmulty(n, m):
    nd = len(str(n).split('.')[1])
    md = len(str(m).split('.')[1])
    return multy(n * pow(10, nd), m * pow(10, md)) / pow(10, md+nd)
```

The idea is to make `n` and `m` integers by shifting the decimal to the right. For instance you have `n = 1.234`, then you need to multiply by `1,000` (`nd=3`). The same for `m` in `md`. Once done, you can use `multy` and divide the result by 1E(nd+md). Let say `m = 5.67` then you have `md = 2`. You then need to divide the result by `1E5`, i.e. `100,000`.